# How to check if IUserRequest.UpdateAsync(User userToUpdate) worked?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to update an attribute of a user in Azure AD, using Microsoft Graph API:

```
await client.Users[userId].Request().UpdateAsync(new User
                    {
                        Id = userId,
                        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                        {
                            [targetAttribute] = value
                        }
                    });
```

It works just fine, but I don't know how to test it now..

Comment: Could you check the property after executing the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean do you want to raise a notification or something like that after completion? for example you can log the result in console or wherever. also you can print the user values to make sure which changes have been applied.

you can do that with ***ContinueWith()*** after async tasks.
here is an example:

```
var t = new Task(); 
t.ContinueWith(o =>{

    if(o.IsFaulted){
        Console.WriteLine(o.Exception?.InnerException);
    return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(o.Result);
  });
```